# Traverse DOM tree of Polymer element

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadow-dom

Is it possible to traverse the DOM subtree when I am using a Polymer element `custom-element` like

```
<polymer-element name="custom-element" attributes="something">
  <template>
  </template>

  <script>
  // access ul and li from the actual DOM here.
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<body>
  <custom-element something="foo">
    <ul>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Hello</li>
    </ul>
  </custom-element>
</body>
```

I want to be able to parameterize my Polymer element using the markup that's wrapped by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `this.children` allows access to them.

```
<polymer-element name="custom-element" attributes="something">
  <template>
  </template>

  <script>
  Polymer({
    created: function() {
      console.log(this.children);
    }
  });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: If you are trying to target only specific kinds of elements be sure to checkout the `<content>` element and its `getDistributedNodes` method.